# Trapezoidal rule to find $\int_{0}^{1} \frac {\cos(2x)}{x^{1/3}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am supposed to find the integration of the given function in the interval $[0,1]$ using trapezoidal rule *(as an assignment problem)*.
$$
\frac {\cos(2x)}{x^\frac{1}{3}}
$$

As it can be seen, the value of the function is not defined at $x=0$ and hence, it seems impossible to find the solution using trapezoidal rule.

Am I thinking the right way, or there exists some method to find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the singularity at the origin is like $\dfrac1{x^{1/3}}$. It is advisable to remove it and integrate it separately:

$$\int_0^1\frac {\cos(2x)}{x^{1/3}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\cos(2x)-1}{x^{1/3}}dx+\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^{1/3}}=-2\int_0^1\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^{1/3}}dx+\frac32x^{2/3}\Big|_0^1.$$

Unfortunately, this form is still unsuitable for trapezoidal interpolation, as the second derivative has a $x^{-1/3}$ factor, making the remainder potentially large (magenta curve).

Alternatively, use the change of variable $x=t^\alpha$, to turn the integral to

$$\alpha\int_0^1\cos(2t^\alpha) t^{\alpha-1-\alpha/3}\,dt.$$

You have the option to choose $\alpha=\frac32$ to get rid of the power factor completely

$$\frac32\int_0^1\cos(2t^{3/2})\,dt,$$
or $\alpha=3$ to avoid fractional exponents
$$2\int_0^1\cos(2t^3)t\,dt.$$

In both cases, the second derivative is well-behaved. You should prefer $\alpha=\frac32$ (blue curve).

[image]

Comment: I think that the same explanation has been provided by @Jack. If there is anything that I might be overlooking, please do mention it.

Comment: Yes, they were the same, explained differently. After deeper thinking, I realized that this approach is unsuitable for the trapezoidal rule and found better solutions.

Comment: Great !! This is completely out of the box idea.

Comment: Yep, remainder analysis shouldn't be forgotten.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, +1 very clever.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit the fact that

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{1/3}}\,dx = \frac{3}{2} $$ 
hence your integral equals:

$$ \frac{3}{2}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^{1/3}}\,dx = \frac{3}{2}-2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{1/3}}\,dx $$
and all the unboundness-issues are gone, since:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{1/3}} = 0.$$

The original integral also equals a series. Since:
$$\cos(2x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n 4^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} $$
it follows that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\cos(2x)\, x^{-1/3}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n 4^n}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{3}{6n+2}=\frac{3}{2}\phantom{}_1 F_2\left(\frac{1}{3};\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3};-1\right)=0.88023061769\ldots.$$

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the complex notation. Could you please tell me what the expression $\frac{3}{2}\phantom{}_1 F_2\left(\frac{1}{3};\frac{1}{2},\frac{4}{3};-1\right)$ means?

Comment: @Gaurav: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: May I dare to ask the reason for the downvote? My answer is essentially the same as Yves Daoust's, just with some detail more on the numerical computation of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

First let's rewrite it as
$$\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^1\frac {\cos(2x)}{x^\frac{1}{3}}
dx
$$
Now let's use integration by parts
$$ u=\cos(2x) $$
$$ du=-2\sin(2x)dx $$
$$ dv=\frac{1}{x^{\frac13}}dx $$
$$ v=\frac32 x^{\frac23} $$
So now we have
$$\frac32\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \left[x^{\frac23} \cos(2x)\bigg|_a^1+2\int_a^1 x^{\frac23}\sin(2x)dx\right]
$$
$$=\frac32\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \left[\cos(2)- a^{\frac23} \cos(2a)\right] +3 \lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \int_a^1 x^{\frac23}\sin(2x)dx
$$
$$=\frac32\cos(2)-\frac32\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \left[ a^{\frac23} \cos(2a)\right] +3 \lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \int_a^1 x^{\frac23}\sin(2x)dx
$$
$$=\frac32\cos(2)-0+3 \lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \int_a^1 x^{\frac23}\sin(2x)dx
$$
$$=\frac32\cos(2)+3 \lim\limits_{a\to 0^+} \int_a^1 x^{\frac23}\sin(2x)dx
$$
Now you can use the trapezoidal rule on the remaining integral. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I'm finding it for 2 intervals. $h=\frac{1-a}{2}$ and the whole expression simplifies to : 
$\frac{1-a}{4} [\frac{cos(2a)}{a^\frac{1}{3}}+cos(2)]+\frac{1-a}{2^\frac{2}{3}}[\frac{cos(1+a)}{(1+a)^\frac{1}{3}}]$. I'm stuck from where I began because on taking limit for $a\rightarrow 0$, it still results in division by zero. Could you please help me out to simplify it further.